# Is there a dateadd scalar function in Google Query Language?

Tags: google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am trying to select rows which are for today or alternatively for tomorrow:

Formula for today is easy (and tidy):

```
=QUERY(A1:B20,"select B where A = toDate(now())")
```

Tomorrow seems more ugly:

```
=QUERY(A1:B4,"select B where A = date '"&TEXT(TODAY()+1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)
```

I searched the GQL documentation for a dateAdd function but couldn't find one.  I tried various things like:

```
=QUERY(A1:B4,"select B where A = toDate(dateadd(now(),1,day))")
```

in case there was an undocumented dateadd function but no joy.  Is there a pretty way of doing this or am I stuck with ugly?

example in:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1azvUwtvWikOgmZfVIs_gjNw3r8Tj4SywVjRnauNUFD8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I think you were close, but this formula seems to work:

```
=QUERY(A1:B4,"select B where A = date '"& TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy-mm-dd" & "'"))
```

That works for today.  For tomorrow just add one to `NOW()`, so you get:

```
=QUERY(A1:B4,"select B where A = date '"& TEXT(NOW()+1,"yyyy-mm-dd" & "'"))
```

Let us know if this is helpful, even if perhaps "ugly".